# how to connect database with javascript

Tags: javascript, database, tryton

I need to connect to a tryton database with javascript, in my research I found some examples like this:

```
var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

But I don't understand what is "Data source", "Initial Catalog", "User ID", "Password" and "Provider"
What do I have to put there?

I know that javascript isn't the best option to connect database but I need to do so.

Thank you very much!
Cristina

Comment: `new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");` — Before you go any further - does your JavaScript environment support ActiveX? e.g. are you using Windows Scripting Host to execute it and not a web browser.

Comment: If you want to use the tryton API to access the database you can use json-rpc client from sao http://hg.tryton.org/sandbox/sao/file/91eeb7dbcb16/src/rpc.js

Comment: If you want to access directly the database it depends on the database backend you use, but generally using a javascript driver for the backend and putting the credentials will do the trick.

Comment: Can not give more advices without more info :(

Answer (score 0):

The data source is the name of the server on the network.

The catalog is a collection of schemas. Effectively, it is the name of the particular database that you want to connect to. (A server can host multiple databases).

User id and Password are authentication credentials. You need to put the username and password you connect to the database using.

Provider is the database driver. You'll probably want to install [an ODBC driver for Postgresql](http://psqlodbc.projects.pgfoundry.org/) and then use [`MSDASQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675326(v=vs.85).aspx).